# Regex for filtering strings not ending in a word

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regex for filtering out perforce changelist descriptions which are not pending.

So string "**Change 358618 on 2013/11/09 by abcdm@abcd_PQRST_UVWXY**" should pass
but string "**Change 358618 on 2013/11/09 by abcdm@abcd_PQRST_UVWXY *pending***" should not.
So far i have come up with the following.

```
($token1,$token2,$token3) = ( $string =~ /^Change\s+([0-9]+)\s+(.*)\s(?!\\*pending\\*)/ );
```

So if the pattern matches i should be able to consume the changelist number. If the changelist is pending, no tokens will be returned.

Answer (score 4):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion, at the end of your expression:

```
(?<!\*pending\*)$
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not solve this problem using Regex as it is an expensive operation. If you are certain that the strings that you wish to exclude ends with *pending* just check that part of the string using offsets:

```
$string1 = 'Change 358618 on 2013/11/09 by abcdm@abcd_PQRST_UVWXY *pending*';
$string2 = '*pending*';

$offset = length($string1) - length($string2);

$result = index($string1, $string2, $offset);
```

Comment: … or `$string2 eq substr $string1, -length $string2`. While this could actually perform better, I am sure you know the quote about *premature optimization*.